# Should I use MongoDB or a relational database management system for this scenario?

Tags: database-design, mongodb, database-recommendation

I have a different item types, each item has different number of attributes some attributes might contain an arbitrary number of values. For example, a building which has `amenities` attribute, this attribute has many different possible values a user should be able to select these values for the item `Building` from a list. Some examples of these values are `Balcony, Pet Allowed, WiFi`. Another item is `Car` this car have different attributes like `Model, Speed, Class` each of them has a single possible value.
In addition to `Attributes` I have a different nested `Categories` for each item, for example a `Vehicle` category, is a parent of `Car` category which is also a parent of `BMW Car` category.
As you can see, the second requirement can be modeled easily for a `Relational Database` but the first one is very hard to model for `Non-relational Database` like `MongoDB`. My app will be used by huge number of users, and both categories and attributes are subject to `Insert/Update/Delete` operations also they may be involved in some reports generation process.

I think about using `MongoDB` as `DBMS`, but I'm not sure yet about this decision.

Comment: You might want to consider adding (a screenshot of) an ERD (Entity Relationship Diagram) to further establish your requirements. Anything is possible and adding more details might increase your chance of finding out for yourself what the best solution might be and provide us with more details to allow us to answer your question. As it currently stands your question could be answered either way.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your base question, why not. Value lists are easy to make, child - parent can be made with [references](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/). You even mix those two to the single key.